# Disable Blue Highlight on Clickable Images on multiple browsers HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm currently learning Web Dev so my answer could be something simple or not, I'm using one CSS file for all my HTML files to style and I've got an issue with an image I added into the header as small icons for Facebook, Twitter, etc.. to link to their sites, but every time I place my mouse over the image, a blue highlight box appears.

I'll need it to work in all browsers. All that happens is a blue box appears below the image.

I don't know if I need to post any code for you to work with, but if so let me know and I'll grab it.

Comment: Please post either a link to your page, a JSFiddle which reproduces the issue, or a screenshot of the problem and the associated code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think css outline:none works, something like

```
a:active {outline: none;}
* {outline: none;}
```

Comment: Haha, my bad, I went to add in the bit of code and noticed I had a:hover 
{
 color:#fff;
 background:#369;
 text-decoration:none;
} so I took it out and it disabled the issue.... wouldn't have found it without your answer though so thank you. (Now I just have to hope I didn't have that in there for a specific reason..nothing else seems to mess up or error when I removed it.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
*:focus {
    outline: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it is not a highlight, but a border:

```
img {
    border: 0;
}
```

or

```
<img src="..." border="0">
```